# How to put condition on button (Ex: Next button ) in HTMl/JS application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating one HTML/JS application in which there are two tab in one of the tab there is input text field and other is having radio button questionnaire.I am using next button to go one tab to another tab ... i want to put condition in next button if input field is empty next button should move to next tab and also show the warning.But i am not able to do it

HTML for input field:-

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullName">Team/Project Name </label>
                            <input type="name" required class="form-control" name="TeamName" id="fullName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter full project name" >
                            <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your team/project name.</small>
                          </div>
<a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
```

HTML for Radio button field:-

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Js for next button :-

```
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: *if input field is empty next button should move* -> should not move ?

Comment: You don't put the condition *on* the button, you put the condition inside the button's event handler.  Specifically, which part are you having trouble with?   How to write [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)?  How to get the [value](https://api.jquery.com/val/) of your input?  How to [find the input](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) (seems you already have this?)  How to [`show`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) an element?

Comment: can you make your code runnable ?